# Camel - How I can define a errorHandler and can use includeRoutes?

Tags: apache-camel

I define my routes in Subclasses and get them in one `RouteBuilder` together with `includeRoutes()`. Now I want to insert a default ErrorHandler but I get the Error Message:

```
errorHandler must be defined before any routes in the RouteBuilder
```

This is my Code:

```
public class defaultRoutes extends RouteBuilder {
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        errorHandler(deadLetterChannel("direct:deadLetter").maximumRedeliveries(3));

        from("direct:deadLetter").id("deadLetter")
            .errorHandler(defaultErrorHandler().disableRedelivery())
            .log("${exception.stacktrace}")
            .setHeader("ErrorMessage",simple("${exception}",String.class))
            .setHeader("ErrorStacktrace",simple("${exception.stacktrace}",String.class))
            .to("activemqWithoutTransactions:errors");

        ...
        ...
        for(String Module: globalConfig.getLoadedModules()) {
            ...
            includeRoutes(routes);
        }
        ...
    }
```

I had also test this:

```
public class defaultRoutes extends RouteBuilder {
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        RouteBuilder errorHandler = new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {
                errorHandler(deadLetterChannel("direct:deadLetter").maximumRedeliveries(3));
                from("direct:deadLetter").id("deadLetter")
                    .errorHandler(defaultErrorHandler().disableRedelivery())
                    .log("${exception.stacktrace}")
                    .setHeader("ErrorMessage",simple("${exception}",String.class))
                    .setHeader("ErrorStacktrace",simple("${exception.stacktrace}",String.class))
                    .to("activemqWithoutTransactions:errors");
            }
        };
        includeRoutes(errorHandler);
        ...
        ...
        for(String Module: globalConfig.getLoadedModules()) {
            ...
            includeRoutes(routes);
        }
        ...
    }
```

But this throw also the same Error Message! What can I do, to get the ErrorHandler to work?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is described in the comments of the issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-5612.

If you use a global scoped errorHandler you have to ensure that it should like the 
following:

- errorHandler
- errorHandler
- route
- route

and not:

- errorHandler
- route
- errorHandler
- route

kind regards,
soilworker

Comment: Look above, i do that! ErrorHandler is the first one! And it works, when i don't do the for-loop and copy there the route in.

Comment: Yes, but maybe in the rest of your routes you add with the for-loop is also an errorhandler?

Comment: Ahhh, you right. There was a errorHandler. This shouldn't happen! Sorry. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `.errorHandler()` line from your route:

```
   from("direct:deadLetter").id("deadLetter")
        .errorHandler(defaultErrorHandler().disableRedelivery()) // this is incorrect
        .log("${exception.stacktrace}")
        .setHeader("ErrorMessage",simple("${exception}",String.class))
        .setHeader("ErrorStacktrace",simple("${exception.stacktrace}",String.class))
        .to("activemqWithoutTransactions:errors");
```

Check [this page](http://camel.apache.org/dead-letter-channel.html) for more usage examples on the Dead Letter Channel in Camel.